# Laravel - select fields in the toJson

Tags: php, json, laravel

If there a way to limit what fields are returned in the toJson method?
I might call toJson on say and index where I only want a couple of columns, and then on another page I might want to return more fields so a single toJson override wont cut it.

Maybe something like

```
toJson(['id', 'name']);
```

so somewhere else I can do

```
toJson(['id', 'name', 'address']);
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing separate trips to the database from different pages of your application. If so then instead of overriding `toJson()` which you can also do, you can just provide an array of columns to `get()` or `all()` method.

```
YourModel::all(['id', 'name'])->toJson();
YourModel::where('age', '<', '65')->get(['id', 'name'])->toJson();
```

and for another page you call it

```
YourModel::all(['id', 'name', 'address'])->toJson();
YourModel::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(['id', 'name', 'address'])->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel includes this now:

```
protected $visible = array('first_name', 'last_name');
```

or

```
protected $hidden = array('password');
```

which are a whitelist/blacklist for toArray and toJson

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json